# Trigger event on element created from data loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fire the click event on an element that is loaded via ajax.
But somehow i cannot select it right to fire the event.

It is basically an image with left, right arrows. if you click on one of the arrows a series of images gets loaded and replaced the images like a gallery. That's works already, i just need to fire the first slide so the user doesn't get that the gallery has been loaded via ajax but was there all the time.

The replacement works fine, but i cannot fire the event on the .slidenav-next element.

There is JS behaviour behind .slidenav-next that needs to be triggered by an click.

Base HTML structure

```
<div><div class="slidecont"><a href="#" class="slide"></a></div></div>
```

JS to fill it with new HTML structure

```
$('body').on('click', '.slide', function(e) {

$.ajax({
  context: this,
  type: "POST",
  url: 'index.php',
  data: {'id':5}
}).done(function(data) {
    $(this).closest('.slidecont').replaceWith(data);

    console.log($(data).find('.slidenav-next'));

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(data).find('.slidenav-next').click();
     }, 200);   
});
});
```

HTML structure that gets loaded via ajax

```
<div><a href="#" class="slidenav-next"></a></div>
```

In the end

```
<div><div><a href="#" class="slidenav-next"></a></div></div>
```

If i load this structure:

```
<div id="xx"><a href="#" class="slidenav-next"></a></div>
```

I can trigger it via:

```
$('#xx > .slidenav-next').click();
or via
$('body').find('.slidenav-next').click();
```

But that's not so clean. I would like to trigger it from within the loaded data.

Comment: do you have something listening for the click? what do you expect to happen as an outcome of the click

Comment: there is behavior behind the .slidenav-next element. i just need to trigger the click event to start it. i already triggered it a different way, but that's no so clean.

Comment: what if you... `var $data = $(data);    $(this).closest('.slidecont').replaceWith($data); $data.find('.slidenav-next').click();`

Comment: that worked, thanks! whats the difference between `$data = $(data); $data.find(...` and `$(data).find(...` ?

Comment: added my thoughts on that as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $data = $(data);
$(this).closest('.slidecont').replaceWith($data);
$data.find('.slidenav-next').click();
```

this way will create a jquery object from the data... that object then gets inserted into the DOM with `replaceWith` and can be referenced later.

just replacing with `data` directly doesnt put the `data` var itself as a element that exists in the DOM and can be referenced from `data`... `data` is still just a string...

---

could also have done something like this at the beginning of the `done` callback..

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = data; //this creates a child element based on the string in data
var dataEle = div.firstChild; //then we take that child
```

now `dataEle` references an element created based on the `data` string that can be inserted (like with `replaceWith(dataEle)`) and referenced later (like with `$(dataEle).find(...`)

---

**More explanation of what was wrong:**

you don't need to insert a jquery object as can be seen in the second example. jquery just takes over the job of creating a dom element and maintains access to it so you can reference it later.

the problem you were having is that `data` was always just a string, you used that string to create a dom element with `replaceWith`... but data itself was still just a string.

then again when you did `$(data).find('.slidenav-next').click();` it was wrapping `data` in a jquery which created it's own element using the string in `data` (although `data` is still just a string) and did indeed fire off the event... however the event got fired off on the the newly created jquery wrapped element that was not ever inserted into the body of the DOM rather than the element you created with `replaceWith`

you were basically creating two elements from the `data` string, putting the first one where you wanted it but then firing off the event on the second one which was never inserted anywhere.

Comment: didn't know that something like a data var element inside the dom existed ;)

Comment: well it's just a var that has some text in it, replaceWith converted that text to put it in the dom... but the var itself was still just the text with no reference to that dom element... wrapping it in jquery lets you reference an object that can reference the dom element... could also have created an element with plain js to put it in if you wanted

Comment: sorry to ask, but when i call a site, all dom elements are not jquery objects, but can still be referenced via jquery. i just don't get it why i need to insert a jquery object. hoping to learn :)

Comment: @Mike - responded in answer